# Is it possible to limit resources of a running app in yarn?

Tags: hadoop-yarn

Sometimes at work I need to use our cluster to run something, but it is used up to 100%, because certain jobs scale up when there are available resources, and my job won't execute for a long time. Is is possible to limit the resources of a running app? Or should we somehow choose a different scheduling policy, if so, then which one?

We use Capacity Scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your apps are, are you 100% coming from large queries (hive app) or from another let's say, spark app.

Spark can eat up the whole cluster easily, even doing almost nothing, that is why you need to define how many cpus to give to those apps, memory, driver memory, etc.

You accomplish that when you do the spark submit, e.g.

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --queue {your yarn queue} {program name} --driver-cores 1 --driver-memory 1G --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 1 -executor-memory 2G
```

That will limit that application to use only those resources (plus a little overhead)

If you have a more complicated environment then you will need to limit by queue, for example, queue1=20% of the cluster with up to 20% only, the default is like queue1 can go up to 100% of the cluster if nobody is using it.

Ideally, you should have several queues with the right limits in place and be really careful with preemption.

Comment: Thanks, with Spark I see, but how do I limit Hive apps? And is it possible to reassign resources equally to each app regardless of how much resources was specified at the start?

Comment: Hive is different, all hive queries go to the AM and get a yarn container to run into, so you need to check the following: Are your queries big or small? are your containers too big for your load? Are all those properties set up correctly? Here: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Demystify-Apache-Tez-Memory-Tuning-Step-by-Step/ta-p/245279, hive should not use a lot unless that you have massive queries or you have wrong memory settings.

Comment: The other thing will be the capacity scheduler, with this one you can limit things within the queues, so the best approach for your issue is to create queues according to your needs, this will even overwrite the input from the user, for example, if the user sends an app with 15 executers, but those breach the limit, then it will stick to the limits.
Here: https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/setting_application_limits.html